# ASP.Net - How do I add a HiddenField from another WebControl and maintain it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, hiddenfield

I've got a WebControl that I want to dynamically add a HiddenField from.

I've tried the following example: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028905/asp-net-webcontrol-page-adding-controls-like-textbox-dynamically), but that doesn't work due to the fact this.Page.Form is null in the Page Init event.

I've tried the following, but the value is never maintained:

```
HiddenField hd_IsDirty = new HiddenField();

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

    this.Controls.Add(hd_IsDirty);
    hd_IsDirty.ID = "hd_IsDirty";

    base.OnInit(e);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

Create the control every time (seems bad!):

```
HiddenField hd_IsDirty = new HiddenField();
```

Tell the Page that the control requires a ControlState OnInit:

```
    this.Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
```

Override the ControlState methods:

```
protected override object SaveControlState()
{

    object obj = base.SaveControlState();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hd_IsDirty.Value))
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            return new Pair(obj, hd_IsDirty.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            return hd_IsDirty.Value;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return obj;
    }
}

protected override void LoadControlState(object state)
{
    if (state != null)
    {
        Pair p = state as Pair;
        if (p != null)
        {
            base.LoadControlState(p.First);
            hd_IsDirty.Value = (string)p.Second;
        }
        else
        {
            if (state is string)
            {
                hd_IsDirty.Value = (string)state;
            }
            else
            {
                base.LoadControlState(state);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres always the dynamic controls placeholder at - http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324003/how-can-i-re-instantiate-dynamic-asp-net-user-controls-without-using-a-database/1324103#1324103) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324003/how-can-i-re-instantiate-dynamic-asp-net-user-controls-without-using-a-database/1324103#1324103).

The answer will show you how to add a control dynamically, which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there no 'magic' way of just adding the control and forgetting about it without using any aspx markup? I don't like the idea of using ViewState as it can be turned on and off.

Comment: Not in ASP.NET it is not like windows, it does not keep it state.

Comment: I know. I was hoping there was a better method I didn't know about. I'll use my answer as it cannot be disabled like ViewState.